# C++20 in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, g++, qt-creator

I want to use `std::source_location` in Qt Creator, I've built the GCC 11.1 and checked it using `g++ main.cpp -std=c++20` that it works. I've created a kit in Qt Creator to use this compiler and I was able to build it by adding:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++2a
```

It works and I can even debug it without issues but Qt keeps saying that I have an error (which is not an error because the build passes):

```
error: no type named 'source_location' in namespace 'std'
```

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: So... to over our bases... you `#include <source_location>`?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica of course, as I said I compiled it successfully using g++ though the terminal.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. It seems to be a Qt bug. You can go to the location of error and replace `std::experimental::source_location` with `std::source_location`. You will get another error after that in another location and just do the same (AFAIR).
Edit: just found this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-93270

Answer (score 4):

It's all about clang's static analysis. The gcc's (or strictly libstdc++'s) header `<source_location>` contains following guard:

```
#if __cplusplus > 201703L && __has_builtin(__builtin_source_location)
```

The guard doesn't allow clang to work as it doesn't support `__builtin_source_location`. Please follow [the clang PR](https://reviews.llvm.org/D120634) that fixes this issue.