# C++ (Clang or GCC): Retrieve method caller function signature

Tags: c++, clang++

Objective:

I want my class method to retrieve the caller function signature. In the same way `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` does for a local function.

Below you encounter a sample code and the output. I want the output 2 to be like 3.

Restriction: MyClass::foo can't be static. Otherwise, it would be enough to create a macro like

```cpp
#define foo() MyClass::foo(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
```

after the class declaration and we would have our solution.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    void foo(const char* parent = __builtin_FUNCTION()) {
        std::cout << "1: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2: " << parent << std::endl;
    }
};

namespace Space
{
    void bar(int notUsedParam){
        MyClass myClass;
        myClass.foo();
        std::cout << "3: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Space::bar(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1: void MyClass::foo(const char*)
2: bar
3: void Space::bar(int)
```

Some Reference:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#source-location-builtins

Comment: What outcome do you want, and why doesn't your macro solution work (`myclass.MyClass::foo(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)`)?  Have you tried a default argument of [`std::source_location::current()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/current)?

Comment: clang implementation of std::source_location has some issues with my IDE.  Explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67707251/c20-in-qt-creator. But yes is a valid

Comment: I am developing under windows, so I also tried compiling with MinGW.  But it only supports the std::experimental::source_location::current(). This implementation only returns the caller function name.

Comment: But according to the documentation that you linked, it should work if I try to compile with GCC under Linux. So I will try to compile it under my Arch later.

Comment: You can see what I am talking about std::experimental::source_location::current()
here is the example: https://onlinegdb.com/dp4lwvkqE

Comment: @Oshio Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636456/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-c-using-gcc-with-line-number-information
It allows you to get full stack trace.